# Why is Gitlab CI re-uploading cache when key is still valid

Tags: angular, gitlab, gitlab-ci, node-modules

in gitlab CI file for an angular project; I define the global cache with the checksum of the package-lock.json file as key. so that the cache is only invalidated when the package-lock.json file changes.

```
cache:
  key:
    files:
      - package-lock.json
  paths:
    - node_modules/
    - .npm
```

**PROBLEM**: cache is still uploaded even when the cache-key is still valid. (see the picture the cache name did not change)

[image]

I want the cache to be uploaded only when it is invalidated, is there anyway to achieve this? or any other remarks recommendations?

Answer (score 4):

By default, the cache is *always* uploaded on success (push-pull policy).

You can change this behavior by configuring the [cache policy](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#cachepolicy). If you want a job to only download the cache, but never upload it, set the cache policy to `pull`. However, you need to make sure at least one previous job populates the cache with either a `push` or `push-pull` policy.

For example:

```yaml
stages:
  - one
  - two

create_cache:
  stage: one
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        - package-lock.json
    paths:
      - node_modules/
      - .npm
    policy: "push-pull"  # default cache behavior
    script:
      - echo "this job is responsible for creating/updating the cache as needed"

other_jobs:
  stage: two
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        - package-lock.json
    paths:
      - node_modules/
      - .npm
    policy: "pull"  # only download cache, do not upload
    script:
      - echo "this will rely on cache being created in previous stage"
```

Unfortunately, there is no configuration to say "push cache if old-cache is invalidated"

Comment: thank you for taking time to reply, unfortunately the configuration you said doesn't exist is what am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

> > Unfortunately, there is no configuration to say "push cache if old-cache is invalidated"
>
> thank you for taking time to reply, unfortunately the configuration you said does not exist is what am looking for.

Regarding the cache policy's capabilities, there is indeed no direct configuration to "push cache if old-cache is invalidated."

However, we can simulate this behavior by combining the [`policy: push-pull` and `policy: pull`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#cachepolicy) settings across different jobs.

```bash
+-------------+       +------------------+       +-----------------+
| package-    |       | GitLab CI Runner |       | Cache Storage   |
| lock.json   |  No   | Cache Check      |  Yes  | Upload Cache    |
| Changed?    +------>+ Cache Policy     +------>+ with push policy|
+-------------+       |                  |       |                 |
                      +------------------+       +-----------------+
```

That would involve two separate jobs within your pipeline:

1. a **create/update cache job**: That job runs with a `push-pull` policy (or `push` if you want to enforce a cache update only from this job). It is responsible for creating or updating the cache whenever necessary, i.e., when `package-lock.json` changes.
2. some **dependent jobs**: These jobs run with a `pull` policy. They only download the cache created by the first job and do not upload it, preventing unnecessary cache uploads when the `package-lock.json` has not changed.

Your `.gitlab-ci.yml` would be:

```yaml
stages:
  - setup
  - build

create_update_cache:
  stage: setup
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        - package-lock.json
    paths:
      - node_modules/
      - .npm
    policy: "push-pull"
  script:
    - npm install

build_project:
  stage: build
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        - package-lock.json
    paths:
      - node_modules/
      - .npm
    policy: "pull"
  script:
    - npm run build
```

The `create_update_cache` is the job that will update the cache whenever `package-lock.json` changes.
The `build_project` and other jobs that follow will use the `pull` policy to only download the cache without re-uploading it.

That does not directly push the cache if the old cache is invalidated, but it manages to prevent unnecessary cache uploads by segregating the responsibility of cache creation and cache usage among different jobs, which should achieve a similar result.

If you want to make sure the cache is only updated when `package-lock.json` changes, you would need to implement a check in the `create_update_cache` script to compare the checksum of `package-lock.json` against a stored value from the previous run and only run `npm install` if it has changed.
However, this would require custom scripting and potentially storing the checksum externally, as GitLab CI does not natively support conditional cache creation based on file changes within the job script itself.